# Laravel 405 Method Not Allowed calling POST method via GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, server

Whenever I am trying to make an ajax call with base64 image in body it gives error as:

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Here is my ajax call:

```
async function addToCart() {

        document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('addToCartButton').style.display = 'none';
        // Get base64URL
        var image = "";
        var full_image = "";
        if (document.getElementById("category_id").value == 'customize back cover') {
            //console.log("652")
            await html2canvas(document.getElementById("html-content-holder")).then(function (canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
                full_image = base64URL;
                image = document.getElementById('selectedImage').src;
            });
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://emlt.thebakeologyindia.com/add_to_cart", // You add the id of the post and the update datetime to the url as well
            data: {
                _token: document.getElementById('token').value,
                user_id: document.getElementById('user_id').value,
                product_id: document.getElementById('product').value,
                quantity: document.getElementById('quantity').value,
                image: image,
                full_image: full_image
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // If not false, update the post
                //console.log(response);
                swal({
                    title: response.data.status,
                    text: response.data.message,
                    icon: response.data.status,
                });
                if(response.data.status == "error")
                {
                document.getElementById('addToCartButton').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else
            {
                document.getElementById('itemInCartLink').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('addToCartButton').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
            }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                document.getElementById('addToCartButton').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
               swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: error.message,
                    icon: "error",
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the form data example:

```
_token: RHJrQ4wX6XbXqi0wOx8sMiFHCuXVI2HclGB3rDco, user_id: 1, product_id: 1, quantity: 1, image:    data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu8AAAH0CAYAAACNesOUAAAgAElEQVR4XoS9iZLjWnIsGMRCAlxy..........,    full_image:    data:image/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBg..........,
```

If I remove the images then it works fine. And it also works perfectly in localhost. This issue occurs in server only.
Here is the link of the website: http://emlt.thebakeologyindia.com/details/1. You can add any other product it will work fine but when you will try to add customize back cover products then this issue occurs because then only I am sending the images. I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Here is the complete error log:

```
{
    "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 256,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 242,
            "function": "methodNotAllowed",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "getRouteForMethods",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 634,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 623,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/MobileCoverEcom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/thebvcgn/emlt.site/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route specifies **POST** method.

But you hitting the method via a **GET** method.

Either correct the method call to POST, or make the route accept both GET and POST

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/action', 'ExampleController@action');
```

Comment: I am using post method in the route i.e. web.php. If I remove the image urls then the same method works fine.

Comment: That's strange.

You can exempt `auth` for that method, and try replicating the same issue via Postman to be sure it's not Ajax sending incorrect requests.

Comment: I am getting the same issue when I am hitting with Postman as well.

Comment: I'll have to recreate your scenario to best understand it's uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

The error states a problem with the route. It indicates that you configured the route to work with get and head verbs yet are using post in the ajax call.

please run:
`php artisan route:list`
to check if the route you're using in the ajax call is loaded.

Comment: I have updated it with the new error log. It seems to work when I don't send base64 image values as string in the body. I think the images are causing some issues but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: would you please show me the routes in routes/web.php

Comment: Route::post('add_to_cart', 'EcommController@addToCart')->middleware('auth');

Comment: Ok good, now the route uses the post verb and that's what we need
but it's receiving a get request and that's the error currently showing.

question is, did you change the type in the ajax call to get? if so you need to change it back to post or if you're trying with postman make sure to use post verb not get

Comment: No, I didn't change the method in the ajax call. Its still post.

Comment: I understand you may have faced the issue only when you added the photo. However, the exception is clearly stating the route not found at a point even before processing the image and that's why all my comments are directed towards route and not the image.

Now another trial, do you possibly call the `addToCart` function from a button in a form? and hence trigering the form url not the ajax?

Comment: Nope. There isn't any form in the whole view page.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely due to the server configuration. Try hosting it in different environment, it will work. I too have faced this issue and I think its due to upload image size php configuration in the server.